# 3 way 90 deg joint

Tags: joints, brackets

Hey I'm looking to buy (8x) this bracket/join to make a studio box but, I'm not able to find the correct name to look up the prices online. What the name of this joint/bracket?

PVC or Metal is don't really matter to much.

See picture(s) bellow.

[image: 3 way 90 deg joint.]

[image: 3 way 90 deg joint.]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This question is awfully close to a "shopping" type connection which is normally not allowed at this site.

You will find plenty of information if you google for:

"3 way tent pole connector"

or

"3 way corner connectors"

Comment: I don't think it's a shop for me question.  The test for me, is if I can google the terms and a bunch of links pop up.  In this case, the asker was wondering what google terms to use, and is therefor on topic.  TL:DR; What am I looking for is on topic.  Where do I buy is off.